# xpath not accepting this expression

Tags: java, xpath, expression

hello everyone i have on question for xpath

/abcd/nsanity/component_details[@component="ucs"]/command_details[**<**configScope inHierarchical="true" cookie="{COOKIE}" dn="org-root" **/>**]/collected_data

i want to retrieve the string for above the xpath statement but when i am giving this xpath to  xpath expression for evaulate it is throwing an exception like

Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location path was expected, but the following token was encountered:  <configScope

Comment: Please show us an example of the data and properly format the code (are the stars contained in your query or not?). Read the [FAQ] on how to format your post.

Comment: no star not containing in my query only < and /> symbols are throwing exception

Comment: If the answer below doesn't meet your expectations, reconsider what I posted in my previous comment. As is, the question is much to vague. What do you mean by "no star not containing in my query"?

Answer (score 2):

The bold part in your XPath expression is not a valid predicate expression. I can only guess, what do you want to achieve. If you want only the `<command_details/>` elements, which have a `<configScope/>` child element with attributes set to `inHierarchical="true"`, `cookie="{COOKIE}"` and `dn="org-root"` then the XPath expression should be:

```
/abcd/nsanity/component_details[@component='ucs']/command_details[configScope[@inHierarchical='true' and @cookie='{COOKIE}' and @dn='org-root']]/collected_data
```

Here is an example XML:

```
<abcd>
  <nsanity>
    <component_details component="ucs">
      <command_details>
        <configScope inHierarchical="true" cookie="{COOKIE}" dn="org-root" />
        <collected_data>Yes</collected_data>
      </command_details>
      <command_details>
        <configScope inHierarchical="true" cookie="{COOKIE}" dn="XXX"/>
        <collected_data>No</collected_data>
      </command_details>
    </component_details>
  </nsanity>
</abcd>
```

The following Java program reads the XML file `test.xml` and evaluates the XPath expression (and prints the text node of element `<collected_data/>`.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse("test.xml");

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath() ;

    NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/abcd/nsanity/component_details[@component='ucs']/command_details[configScope[@inHierarchical='true' and @cookie='{COOKIE}' and @dn='org-root']]/collected_data", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
      Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
      System.out.println(el.getTextContent());
    }
  }
}
```